# Build a CSV with 4 columns and 2 variables

Tags: ruby, csv

Here's my sample stuff:

```
    my_csv_to_export = CSV.generate do |csv| 
        csv << %w(dates orders)
        orders.each do |elem| 
            csv << elem
        end
        csv << %w(dates sales)
        sales.each do |elem| 
            csv << elem
        end
    end
```

CSV is ok but with only 2 columns, I need headers %w(dates orders dates sales) in 4 column

Does someone got a clue ? I'll own you a pint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your piece of Ruby code, you have inserted rows of 2 columns each, at every step. So, initially the records in **orders** are inserted and below which the records in **sales** are inserted. If you need them laid side-by-side, you could read the i-th row in **orders** and i-th row in **sales**, merge them as a single row of 4 columns and insert into the CSV.

```rb
my_csv_to_export = CSV.generate do |csv|
    header = %w(dates orders dates sales) 
    csv << header
    padding_row = ["", ""] 
    total_number_of_rows = [orders.size, sales.size].max

    # If one array contains more rows than other, 
    # fill the empty row with the padding_row so that
    # the alignment of records in the CSV is preserved.

    (0..(total_number_of_rows - 1)).each do |row_index|
        current_row = (orders[row_index] || padding_row) + (sales[row_index] || padding_row)
        csv << current_row
    end
end
```

If the arrays namely orders and sales already contain the entries in the order of dates, then you could just replace the following two assignment statements.

```rb
header = %w(dates orders sales)
.
.
.
current_row = (orders[row_index] || padding_row) + [(sales[row_index] || padding_row)[1]]
```

A better solution would be to create a map from date to order and another map from date to sales. Then date can be used to fetch the order from order map and sales from sales map provided the **formatting of date is the same** in both the arrays.

```rb
my_csv_to_export = CSV.generate do |csv|
    header = %w(dates orders sales) 
    csv << header

    // The following code assumes that there is only one order/sale per date.
    orders_map = orders.index_by { |order| order[0] } // Use the first column of the array i.e date as the key to the map.
    sales_map = sales.index_by { |sale| sale[0] }
    unique_dates = (orders_map.keys + sales_map.keys).uniq

    unique_dates.each do |date|
        csv << [date, orders[date] || "", sales[date] || ""]
    end
end
```

Comment: That works perfectly Aravind, thanks ! And what about if I don't want the dates to be repeated ? Like :
    header = %w(dates orders sales)